# Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Tags: python, mysql, json, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I want to create SQL tables for json data usign python 3 google colab.
Here is the code:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Text, DateTime, Float, Boolean, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

total_data = [
    {
        "fields": {
            "bkdate": None,
            "business_credit_card_total_balances": None,
            "business_credit_card_total_limits": None,
            "business_total_monthly_debt_payments": None,
            "business_total_mortgage_monthly_payments": None,
            "created_at": "2016-08-04T00:29:03.067Z",
            "detail_results": None,
            "error_reason": "no reasons",
            "fico_v2": "695",
            "fico_v3": None,
            "loanapp_id": 194,
            "personal_credit_card_total_balances": None,
            "personal_credit_card_total_limits": None,
            "personal_total_monthly_payments": None,
            "report_type": "CreditProfile",
            "result": True,
            "role": "applicant",
            "total_mortgage_monthly_payments": None,
            "username": "cho",
            "version": "CF Microloan"
            },
        "model": "common.prequalresult",
        "pk": 1
    }
]

engine = create_engine('mysql://user:password@localhost:5432/my_data', echo=False)

Base = declarative_base()


class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    pk = Column(Integer, primary_key=False)
    model = Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    child = relationship('Comment', backref='article', uselist=False)

class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comment'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    bkdate = Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    business_credit_card_total_balances = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    business_credit_card_total_limits = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    business_total_monthly_debt_payments= Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    business_total_mortgage_monthly_payments= Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    detail_resultsColumn(String(100), nullable=True)
    created_at = Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    error_reason = Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    fico_v2= Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    fico_v3= Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    loanapp_id= Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    personal_credit_card_total_balances= Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    personal_credit_card_total_limits= Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    personal_total_monthly_payments= Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    report_type= Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    result= Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    role= Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    total_mortgage_monthly_payments= Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    username= Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    version= Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    article_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('article.id'))


x = Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

for temp_data in total_data:
    pk = temp_data['pk']
    model = temp_data['model']
    bkdate = temp_data['fields']['bkdate']
    business_credit_card_total_balances = temp_data['fields']['business_credit_card_total_balances']
    created_at = temp_data['fields']['created_at']
    business_credit_card_total_limits = temp_data['fields']['business_credit_card_total_limits']
    business_total_monthly_debt_payments = temp_data['fields']['business_total_monthly_debt_payments']
    business_total_mortgage_monthly_payments = temp_data['fields']['business_total_mortgage_monthly_payments']
    detail_resultsColumn = temp_data['fields']['detail_resultsColumn']
    error_reason = temp_data['fields']['error_reason']
    fico_v2 = temp_data['fields']['fico_v2']
    fico_v3 = temp_data['fields']['fico_v3']
    loanapp_id = temp_data['fields']['loanapp_id']
    personal_credit_card_total_balances = temp_data['fields']['personal_credit_card_total_balances']
    personal_credit_card_total_limits = temp_data['fields']['personal_credit_card_total_limits']
    personal_total_monthly_payments = temp_data['fields']['personal_total_monthly_payments']
    report_type = temp_data['fields']['report_type']
    result = temp_data['fields']['result']
    role = temp_data['fields']['role']
    total_mortgage_monthly_payments = temp_data['fields']['total_mortgage_monthly_payments']
    username= temp_data['fields']['username']
    version = temp_data['fields']['version']
    article_id = temp_data['fields']['article_id']

    parent1 = Article(pk=temp_data['pk'], model=model)
    child = Comment(bkdate=bkdate,
                    business_credit_card_total_balances=business_credit_card_total_balances,
                    created_at=created_at,
                    business_credit_card_total_limits=business_credit_card_total_limits,
                    business_total_monthly_debt_payments=business_total_monthly_debt_payments,
                    business_total_mortgage_monthly_payments=business_total_mortgage_monthly_payments,
                    detail_resultsColumn=detail_resultsColumn,
                    error_reason=error_reason,
                    fico_v2=fico_v2,
                    fico_v3=fico_v3,
                    loanapp_id=loanapp_id,
                    personal_credit_card_total_balances=personal_credit_card_total_balances,
                    personal_credit_card_total_limits=personal_credit_card_total_limits,
                    personal_total_monthly_payments=personal_total_monthly_payments,
                    report_type=report_type,
                    result=result,
                    role=role,
                    total_mortgage_monthly_payments=total_mortgage_monthly_payments,
                    username=username,
                    version=version,
                    article_id=article_id,
                    article=parent1)

    session.add(parent1)
    session.add(child)

session.commit()
```

> It shows the error when I execute the code above: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb' .
>   The code include the data and using SQLAlchemy ORM to create tables. Does anyone has another method to create SQL tables for the data?

I installed the module using :

```
!pip install PyMySQL
```

I do not know how to fix it.Can someone help with it?

Answer (score 1):

```
  pip3 install pymysql
```

this is how your connection uri syntax should be:

```
 'mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost:3306/myDb'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how to use mysql in colab.

You can adapt it to your problem. It use PyMySQL instead of MySQLdb.

```py
# install, set connection
!apt-get install mysql-server > /dev/null
!service mysql start
!mysql -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root'"
!pip -q install PyMySQL
%load_ext sql
%config SqlMagic.feedback=False 
%config SqlMagic.autopandas=True
%sql mysql+pymysql://root:root@/
# query using %sql or %%sql
df = %sql SELECT Host, User, authentication_string FROM mysql.user
df
```